# Angular mousedown/mouseover on table cells

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I want to highlight table cells on mousedown/mouseover behaviour. So whenever I have the mouse pressed and hover over a cell, it shall be highlighted.

In this simple example, there is a small issue: on every second click the mouse gets stuck with the disable-symbol (see screenshot), and the mousedown will not fire until I perform another click.

[image]

HTML:

```
<table>
  <tr *ngFor="let rows of groups">
    <td *ngFor="let cell of rows.row" 
        (mousedown)="down(cell)" 
        (mouseover)="over(cell)"
        (mouseup)="up()"
        [class.active]="cell.isChecked"
    ></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

TS:

```
  active: boolean = false

  down(b) {
    this.active = true
    if (this.active)
      b.isChecked = !b.isChecked
  }

  over(b) {
    if (this.active) 
      b.isChecked = !b.isChecked
  }

  up() {
    this.active = false
  }
```

Is it an event issue of the mouse, browser related or code related?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simbol must be related to drag-n-drop feature. Try to add the following attributes to the `td` element.

```
ondragstart="return false;" ondrop="return false;"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

.html

```
<table>
  <tr *ngFor="let rows of groups">
    <td *ngFor="let cell of rows.row" 
        (mouseleave)="!cell.isSelected ? cell.isChecked = true : false" 
        (mouseover)="cell.isChecked = false"
        (click)="cell.isSelected = !cell.isSelected"
        [class.active]="cell.isChecked"
    ></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

.ts

```
groups = [
  {
  row: [
    { isChecked: true, src: "",isSelected :false},
    { isChecked: true, src: "",isSelected :false},
    { isChecked: true, src: "",isSelected :false},
    { isChecked: true, src: "",isSelected :false},
    { isChecked: true, src: "",isSelected :false},
    { isChecked: true, src: "",isSelected :false}
  ],
   ...
 }
```

**[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-j9c2d4?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html)**